How to choose between measure and visual calculation approach for running total?
I need to show the running sum. There seems to be approach using measure and using visual calculation. On what basis do I make a choice of the approach?
Measure example:
Running Total MEASURE = 

CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Sales'[amt] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Sales' ),
        'Sales'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Sales'[Date] )
    )
)

Visual calculation example:
SalesUpToDate = RUNNINGSUM([SalesAmount], Rows)


If you are comfortable with DAX, prefer measures. Visual Calculations have way too many limitations. For example, they are not part of the data model but a part of a specific visual; you can't refer to them, you can't reuse them in other calculations, etc. The only use I can think of is potential performance improvement over complex measures - since visual calcs are performed on the aggregated data, they can be meaningfully faster in some cases.

Definitely prefer measures as they can be reused and don't suffer the same drawbacks that visual calcs currently do.
